# lumen/laravel Eloquent hasManyThrough 3 models relation

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, has-many-through, lumen, belongs-to

I try to acomplish a relation with 3 models:

```
Cities.php //table cities
id
name

Neighbourhoods.php //table neighbourhoods
id
name
city_id

Blocks.php //table blocks
id
name
neighbourhood_id
```

My models looks like this:
Cities.php

```
public function neighbourhoods()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Neighbourhoods', 'App\Blocks', 'neighbourhood_id', 'city_id', 'id');
}
```

Neighbourhoods.php

```
public function blocks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Blocks', 'neighbourhood_id', 'id');
}
```

Blocks.php

```
public function neighbourhoods()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Neighbourhoods', 'neighbourhood_id', 'id');
}
```

The result shoud be:

```
results
 city1:
  neighbourhoods:
   neighbourhood1:
    block1
    block2
    block3
   neighbourhood2
    block1
    block2
 city2:
  neighbourhoods:
   neighbourhood1:
    blocks:
     block1
     block2
     block3
   neighbourhood2:
    blocks:
     block1
     block2
```

Calling the results:

```
return Blocks::with('neighbourhoods')->get();
```

I know that my models are not properly named. City (singular), Neighbourhood (singlar), Block (singular) but passing parameters shoud work.
I just can't figure our why it does not work.

**RELATIONSSHIP SOLUTION based on @Gaurav Rai's response**

First of all, my models are wrong named. Please condider naming your database using plurals for example: cities, neighbourhoods, blocks and your models singular for example: City.php, Neighbourhood.php and Block.php

Based on my problem, the solution is:

Cities.php

```
public function neighbourhoods()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Neighbourhoods', 'city_id', 'id');
     // because my model is called Cities.php,
     // the function will look by default 
     // for the column cities_id in neighbourhoods table, 
     // thats why we need to specifiy city_id column
}

public function blocks()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Blocks', 'App\Neighbourhoods', 'city_id', 'neighbourhood_id', 'id');
}
```

Neighbourhoods.php

```
public function cities()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Cities', 'city_id', 'id');
}

public function blocks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Blocks', 'neighbourhood_id','id');
}
```

Blocks.php

```
public function neighbourhoods()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Neighbourhoods', 'neighbourhood_id');
}
```

Calling the relation:

```
return Cities::with(['neighbourhoods', 'blocks'])->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your relationships are not well defined:

Cities.php

```
public function neighbourhoods()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Neighbourhoods');
}
public function blocks()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Neighbourhoods', 'App\Blocks');
}
```

Neighbourhoods.php

```
public function blocks()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Blocks');//by default it will consider id
}
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
}
```

Blocks.php

```
public function neighbourhoods()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Neighbourhoods');
}
```